# Не работает страница 404 на сайте

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Суть проблемы:
Есть сайт https://newmathdata.com/
На сайте создана страница 404.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С первого взгляда, настройки 404 в вордпрессе верны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то 404 на сайте не работает.
https://newmathdata.com/dgfdgdf

Помогите разобраться в чём причина.

Comment: Потому что сервер надо нормально  настраивать.  А то даже кодировака не правильная.

Comment: Спасибо. Как правильно настроить кодировку и сервер?

Comment: Обратиться к документации сервера или сисадминам